# feature selection f_classif scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I want to use scikit-Learn for feature selection. I want to reduce my input features with a univariate selection and the SelectKBest-methode, so that I get the most important features. I need it for a binary classification task (Output: -1/+1).

I want to use f_classif.
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.f_classif.html

The documentation says that it needs a data matrix for Y. The comparable chi2-mehode needs simply the target vector in Y. 
(http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.chi2.html#sklearn.feature_selection.chi2).

In different examples using f_classif the target vector (classes of the Input) is presented for Y.

What is the difference between the target vector and the data matrix in that case? Can I simply use the target vector Y or should I keep something in mind?

My Code:

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
from sklearn.feature_selection import f_classif
import numpy

dataset = numpy.loadtxt("training2.txt", delimiter=";")
X = dataset[:,0:3]
y = dataset[:,3:4]
y = y.ravel()

select = SelectKBest(f_classif,k=2)
select.fit(X,y)

mask = select.get_support()
print(mask)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ..go try it out and get wet feet... its called research. Comeback with your code by modifying it and tell us then what goes wrong. Your question hit unnecessarily triage review. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and modify question accordingly to minimal working example. Without posting your code you risk removal of your question.

Comment: I have added my Code. Thanks for your response. I get the mask I expected but I do not know, if it is really what I wanted (if the correct computations have run).

Comment: If you add an small but working example array set and what you expect as "detailed" result but fail to get that than that should also be in your question. With a missing `training2.txt` data-set its hard to know what you are looking for and sneak-peak over your shoulder.

Comment: Before I use it for my complex data set, I have tried a simple one (2 Inputs, simply points in a coordinate system with 2 different classes) and just added a random noisy variable. The code worked and it excluded this extra variable. I wonder whether it works for big data sets, too. So, my question is why in the documentation of scikit-learn a "data matrix" is needed for y, instead of just calling it the target vector like in the chi2 or mutual_info_classif documentation?

Comment: What is the difference between y="array-like, shape = (n_samples,) "(chi2) and y="array of shape(n_samples)" (f_classif)? I know it's just a tiny thing, but I am not very familiar with scikit and want to improve my skills...